# Will it be possible to use GTK3.2's HTML5 extension in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gtk3, html5

Does anybody know whether or not it will be possible to use the GTK3.2's new HTML5-extension in Ubuntu 12.04? They announced that GNOME3.2 will be included, but will they build the GTK packages with the new HTML5-extension enabled? Unfortunately thy did not in 11.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apparently not:

```
$ GDK_BACKEND=broadway gnome-calculator

Gdk-ERROR **: Unsupported GDK backend: broadway
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

You could try to create a bugreport for the Ubuntu GTK3 package, asking to compile it with --enable-broadway-backend

[GTK3 Ubuntu source package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gtk+3.0)

Comment: FYI, bug is already reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/933641

Answer (score 4):

I created a PPA with a Broadway-backend enabled GTK+.

You can find it [here](https://launchpad.net/~malizor/+archive/gtk-broadway).